# How to upload files directly from the frontend to the Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a basic Express server and a front-end application. When the user clicks a submit button, I want to send a request to the Express server, which should, in turn, generate a signed URL for a Google Cloud Storage bucket. Once the signed URL is successfully obtained from Google Cloud Storage, it will be sent back to the frontend in order to make a write request to the bucket with the selected input video file.
I have seen few tutorials being able to do this with AWS S3 bucket, but I couldn't find one with Google Storage Bucket. I tried using this code :-

```js
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'something',
    keyFilename: 'test.json'
});

async function generateSignedUrl(bucketName, objectName) {
    const expiration = new Date();
    expiration.setMinutes(expiration.getMinutes() + 15);
  
    const signedUrl = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(objectName).getSignedUrl({
      version: 'v4',
      action: 'write',
      expires: expiration,
    });
  
    return signedUrl;
  }

// Your route to handle the request for a signed URL
app.get('/signed-url', async (req, res) => {
    const bucketName = 'mycompanytestbucket';
    const objectName = 'your-file-namethree.txt';
    console.log('welcome')
  
    const signedUrl = await generateSignedUrl(bucketName, objectName);
  
    // Console log the signed URL
    console.log(signedUrl);
  
    // Send the signed URL back to the client
    res.send(signedUrl);
  });
```

and on the frontend :-

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/signed-url');
  const signedUrl = await response.text();
  const file = imageInput.files[0]

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", signedUrl, true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
    const status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
        alert("File is uploaded");
    } else {
        alert("Something went wrong!");
    }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
    alert("Something went wrong");
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
    xhr.send(file);
```

But when I run the code, select a file, and click on the submit button, I get this error:-

```
Failed to load resource: http://127.0.0.1:5500/frontend/[%22https://storage.googleapis.com/mycompanybucket/your-file-namethree.txt?X-G the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I also enabled the *allUsers* permission from the google cloud bucket permissions, but it still prompt with the same error.

Any guide on achieving this would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `method` in the signed URL creation (it works like that in  Python). Also add the content type

```
    const signedUrl = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(objectName).getSignedUrl({
      version: 'v4',
      method: 'PUT',
      action: 'write',
      expires: expiration,
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    });
```